# Border check in image processing

Tags: c, arm, simd, neon

I want to take care the border conditions while handling any filters in image processing .I am extrapolating the border and creating the new boundary.For example I am having 4x3 input :

```
//Input
int image[4][3] = 
1 2 3 4 
2 4 6 8 
3 6 9 12

//Output
int extensionimage[6][5] =
1 1 2 3 4 4
1 1 2 3 4 4 
2 2 4 6 8 8
3 3 6 9 12 12
3 3 6 9 12 12
```

My code :

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

void padd_border(int *img,int *extension,int width,int height);

int main(){
    int width = 4,height = 3;
    int *img =  new int[(width) * (height)];
    for(int j = 0;j < height; j++){
        for(int i = 0;i < width; i++){
            img[j*width + i] = (i+1)*(j+1);
            printf("%d\t",img[j*width + i]);
        }
    }
    //Allocate memory for signal extension
    int *extension =  new int[(width + 2) * (height + 2)];

    //Check memory allocation
    if (!extension)
        return 0;

    // init to zero
    memset(extension, 0, sizeof(int)*(width + 2) * (height + 2));

    //Padd the input for border conditions
    padd_border(img,extension,width,height);
    //HERE using "extension" input for dummy functionality 

    delete[] extension;
    delete[] img;

    return 0;
}

void padd_border(int *image,int *extension,int width,int height){

    //   Create image extension
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    {
        memcpy(extension + (width + 2) * (i + 1) + 1, image + width * i, width * sizeof(int));
        extension[(width + 2) * (i + 1)] = image[width * i];
        extension[(width + 2) * (i + 2) - 1] = image[width * (i + 1) - 1];
    }

    //   Fill first line of image extension
    memcpy(extension, extension + width + 2, (width + 2) * sizeof(int));
    //   Fill last line of image extension
    memcpy(extension + (width + 2) * (height + 1), extension + (width + 2) * height, (width + 2) * sizeof(int));
}
```

My questions:

1) I don't want to create "extension" buffer. I want to reuse the image for doing the extrapolation. So is it possible ?

2) How can I use Neon to do so wrt my above code ?

After Changing the code according to PaulR pseudo code ,I am getting some strange results :

Editing My question for run time issues during fixing the border
My Input :

```
221 220 221 223 230 233 234 235 ..
71  73  70  70  92  130 141 143 ..
```

I want to this operation to get destination :

```
 -1*v_m1_m1 + 0*v_m1_0 + 1*v_m1_p1
 -1*v_0_m1  + 0*v_0_0  + 1*v_0_p1       ->V_OUT
 -1*v_p1_m1 + 0*v_p1_0 + 1*v_p1_p1
```

after changing the code for border I am getting below valuse:

```
    221 221 221 221    221 220 221 223   230 233 234 235
    221 221 221 221    221 220 221 223   230 233 234 235
    71  71  71  71     71  73  70  70    92  130 141 143
```

In scalar code if I want to calculate for 221 (@i,j =0,0) ,With border it is looking like this :

```
 221 221 220
 221 221 220
 71  71  73
```

But with vectorization in Neon ,I am getting which is wrong

```
v_m1_m1.0  v_m1_0.1  v_m1_p1.2
v_0_m1.0   v_0_0.1   v_0_p1.2
v_p1_m1.0  v_p1_0.1  v_p1_p1.2


221 221 230 
221 221 230
71  71  92
```

my  pseudo code:

```
for i = 0 to nrows - 1
        // init row pointers
        p_row_m1 = src + src_width * MAX(i-1, 0);           // pointing to minus1 row
        p_row_0  = src + src_width * i;                     // pointing to current row
        p_row_p1 = src + src_width * MIN(i+1, src_width-1); // pointing to plus1 row

        v_m1_m1 = vdupq_n_u32(p_row_m1[0]);   // fill left vector from src[i-1][0]
        v_0_m1  = vdupq_n_u32(p_row_0[0]);    // fill left vector from src[i][0]
        v_p1_m1 = vdupq_n_u32(p_row_p1[0]);   // fill left vector from src[i+1][0]

        v_m1_0 = vld1q_u32(&p_row_m1[0]);   // load center vector from src[i-1][0..7]
        v_0_0  = vld1q_u32(&p_row_0[0]);    // load center vector from src[i][0..7]
        v_p1_0 = vld1q_u32(&p_row_p1[0]);   // load center vector from src[i+1][0..7]

        for j = 0 to (ncols - 4) step 4         // assuming 4 elements per SIMD vector

            v_m1_p1  = vld1q_u32(&p_row_m1[j+4]);   // load right vector from src[i-1][0..7]
            v_0_p1   = vld1q_u32(&p_row_0[j+4]);    // load right vector from src[i][0..7]
            v_p1_p1  = vld1q_u32(&p_row_p1[j+4]);   // load right vector from src[i+1][0..7]
    //
    // you now have a 3x3 arrangement of vectors on which
    // you can perform a neighbourhood operation and generate
    // 16 output pixels for the current iteration:
    //
    //    v_m1_m1  v_m1_0  v_m1_p1
    //    v_0_m1   v_0_0   v_0_p1
    //    v_p1_m1  v_p1_0  v_p1_p1
    //
    //               |
    //               V
    //
    //              v_out
    vst1q_s32(v_out, &image_out[i][j])      // store output vector at image_out[i][j..j+15]
    // shuffle vectors so that we can use them on next iteration
    v_m1_m1 = v_m1_0
    v_m1_0  = v_m1_p1

    v_0_m1  = v_0_0 
    v_0_0   = v_0_p1

    v_p1_m1 = v_p1_0
    v_p1_0  = v_p1_p1

  end_for
  // for final iteration we need to handle right edge pixels...
  v_m1_p1 = vdupq_n_u32(p_row_m1[ncols-1])     // fill right vector from image[i-1][ncols-1]
  v_0_p1  = vdupq_n_u32(p_row_0[ncols-1])       // fill right vector from image[i][ncols-1]
  v_p1_p1 = vdupq_n_u32(p_row_p1[ncols-1])     // fill right vector from image[i+1][ncols-1]
  // calculate v_out as above
  vst1q_s32(v_out, &image_out[i][j])        // store output vector at image_out[i][ncols_16..ncols-1]
end_for
```

Comment: It's fairly easy to do in the Y axis (just load your neigbourhood vectors from a clipped Y index), but a bit fiddly in the X axis. For the X axis you typically need to initialise an X neighbourhood vector for the negative indices prior to entering the X axis loop. If I get time I'll post a detailed answer with some examples.

Comment: @PaulR,I understood below points from your reply 1) I have to use the extension buffer .I can not get ride of this extra memory creation . (2)With present implementation logic(as per my code) I can follow your suggestion

Comment: No, you don't need the extra buffer - the neighbourhood vectors I referred to are just Neon (128 bit) variables.

Comment: Paul if you don't mind can you explain bit !

Comment: If I get time I'll post a complete answer with examples - in the mean time look at some of the existing SIMD questions on StackOverflow - I'm sure I've answered similar questions before (probably for SSE, but the same principles apply).

Comment: OK - I've now added some pseudo code in an answer below which illustrates some common techniques for SIMD processing of a 2D image including border pixels.

Comment: @PaulR ,I have added my pseudo code in my question  .I am having some queries .There are few instructions that NEON don't have as like SIMD .Can you just comment on my edited questions part

Comment: Please note that StackOverflow is not a discussion forum - please don't keep piggybacking new questions onto an existing question. I answered the original question for you - if you're happy with the answer then you should up-vote and/or accept it and move on. If you have further questions then you should start one or more new questions (and I'll be happy to look at them and try and answer if I can).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo code for performing a 3x3 neighbourhood operation using SIMD with replicated edge pixels. Input image is `image[nrows][ncols]`, output image is `image_out[nrows][ncols]`.

```
for i = 0 to nrows - 1
  // init row pointers
  p_row_m1 = &image[max(i-1, 0)][0]         // pointer to start of row i-1
  p_row_0 = &image[i][0]                    // pointer to start of row i
  p_row_p1 = &image[min(i+1, ncols-1)][0]   // pointer to start of row i+1
  v_m1_m1 = init_vec(p_row_m1[0])           // fill left vector from image[i-1][0]
  v_0_m1 = init_vec(p_row_0[0])             // fill left vector from image[i][0]
  v_p1_m1 = init_vec(p_row_p1[0])           // fill left vector from image[i+1][0]
  v_m1_0 = load_vec(&p_row_m1[0])           // load centre vector from image[i-1][0..15]
  v_0_0 = load_vec(&p_row_0[0])             // load centre vector from image[i][0..15]
  v_p1_0 = load_vec(&p_row_p1[0])           // load centre vector from image[i+1][0..15]
  for j = 0 to (ncols - 16) step 16         // assuming 16 elements per SIMD vector
    v_m1_p1 = load_vec(&p_row_m1[j+16])     // load right vector from image[i-1][0..15]
    v_0_p1 = load_vec(&p_row_0[j+16])       // load right vector from image[i][0..15]
    v_p1_p1 = load_vec(&p_row_p1[j+16])     // load right vector from image[i+1][0..15]
    //
    // you now have a 3x3 arrangement of vectors on which
    // you can perform a neighbourhood operation and generate
    // 16 output pixels for the current iteration:
    //
    //    v_m1_m1  v_m1_0  v_m1_p1
    //    v_0_m1   v_0_0   v_0_p1
    //    v_p1_m1  v_p1_0  v_p1_p1
    //
    //               |
    //               V
    //
    //              v_out
    //
    store_vec(v_out, &image_out[i][j])      // store output vector at image_out[i][j..j+15]
    // shuffle vectors so that we can use them on next iteration
    v_m1_m1 = v_m1_0
    v_m1_0  = v_m1_p1
    v_0_m1  = v_0_0 
    v_0_0   = v_0_p1
    v_p1_m1 = v_p1_0
    v_p1_0  = v_p1_p1
  end_for
  // for final iteration we need to handle right edge pixels...
  v_m1_p1 = init_vec(p_row_m1[ncols-1])     // fill right vector from image[i-1][ncols-1]
  v_0_p1 = init_vec(p_row_0[ncols-1])       // fill right vector from image[i][ncols-1]
  v_p1_p1 = init_vec(p_row_p1[ncols-1])     // fill right vector from image[i+1][ncols-1]
  // calculate v_out as above
  store_vec(v_out, &image_out[i][j])        // store output vector at image_out[i][ncols_16..ncols-1]
end_for
```

Note that this assumes 16 pixels per vector and also that `ncols` is a multiple of 16.

Comment: ,I am not getting this logic ..Why it is pointing to same row 1st element  ??     p_row_p1 = image[min(i+1, ncols-1)]   When i = 0;                                                   image[min(1, ncols-1)] = image[1] which is not image[1][0] !!

Comment: Because you want the edge pixels to be replicated for the first row (when i = 0) - so the first two row pointers point to the same row. When i = 1 then they point at different rows. I've edited the row pointer initialisation to make it a little clearer.

Comment: I think image[width*1] will point to second row not image[1] !!

Comment: I edited it a few minutes ago to make the intention of the row pointer initialisation clearer - the logic is the same but hopefully it's less confusing now.

Comment: can I write this way :                                                                                   p_row_m1 = image + nclos * max(i-1, 0) 
p_row_0  = image + nclos * [i] 
p_row_p1 = image + nclos*(min(i+1, ncols-1))

Comment: It's pretty hard to read code in comments - try studying the pseudo code for a while until you understand the logic. Once you understand the logic then the implementation details should not be too difficult.