# Border check with neon

Tags: arm, simd, neon

With reference to my earlier question for border check condition -
[Border check in image processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29518845/border-check-in-image-processing)?
I am writing code with neon for border check.I am having below issues when writing the code :

Input :

```
 --------------------------------
|221 220 228 223 230 233 234 235 ..
|71  73  70  78  92  130 141 143 ..
|
```

Requirement:

```
  -1 * v_m1_m1 + 0 * v_m1_0 + 1 * v_m1_p1
  -1 * v_0_m1  + 0 * v_0_0  + 1 * v_0_p1    --> v_out
  -1 * v_p1_m1 + 0 * v_p1_0 + 1 * v_p1_p1
```

Pseudo Code:

```
for i = 0 to nrows - 1
        // init row pointers
        p_row_m1 = src + src_width * MAX(i-1, 0);           // pointing to minus1 row
        p_row_0  = src + src_width * i;                     // pointing to current row
        p_row_p1 = src + src_width * MIN(i+1, src_width-1); // pointing to plus1 row

        v_m1_m1 = vdupq_n_u32(p_row_m1[0]);   // fill left vector from src[i-1][0]
        v_0_m1  = vdupq_n_u32(p_row_0[0]);    // fill left vector from src[i][0]
        v_p1_m1 = vdupq_n_u32(p_row_p1[0]);   // fill left vector from src[i+1][0]

        v_m1_0 = vld1q_u32(&p_row_m1[0]);   // load center vector from src[i-1][0..7]
        v_0_0  = vld1q_u32(&p_row_0[0]);    // load center vector from src[i][0..7]
        v_p1_0 = vld1q_u32(&p_row_p1[0]);   // load center vector from src[i+1][0..7]

        for j = 0 to (ncols - 4) step 4         // assuming 4 elements per SIMD vector

            v_m1_p1  = vld1q_u32(&p_row_m1[j+4]);   // load right vector from src[i-1][0..7]
            v_0_p1   = vld1q_u32(&p_row_0[j+4]);    // load right vector from src[i][0..7]
            v_p1_p1  = vld1q_u32(&p_row_p1[j+4]);   // load right vector from src[i+1][0..7]
    //
    // you now have a 3x3 arrangement of vectors on which
    // you can perform a neighbourhood operation and generate
    // 16 output pixels for the current iteration:
    //
    //    v_m1_m1  v_m1_0  v_m1_p1
    //    v_0_m1   v_0_0   v_0_p1
    //    v_p1_m1  v_p1_0  v_p1_p1
    //
    //               |
    //               V
    //
    //              v_out
    vst1q_s32(v_out, &image_out[i][j])      // store output vector at image_out[i][j..j+15]
    // shuffle vectors so that we can use them on next iteration
    v_m1_m1 = v_m1_0
    v_m1_0  = v_m1_p1

    v_0_m1  = v_0_0 
    v_0_0   = v_0_p1

    v_p1_m1 = v_p1_0
    v_p1_0  = v_p1_p1

      end_for
      // for final iteration we need to handle right edge pixels...
      v_m1_p1 = vdupq_n_u32(p_row_m1[ncols-1])     // fill right vector from image[i-1][ncols-1]
      v_0_p1  = vdupq_n_u32(p_row_0[ncols-1])       // fill right vector from image[i][ncols-1]
      v_p1_p1 = vdupq_n_u32(p_row_p1[ncols-1])     // fill right vector from image[i+1][ncols-1]
      // calculate v_out as above
      vst1q_s32(v_out, &image_out[i][j])        // store output vector at image_out[i][ncols_16..ncols-1]
    end_for
```

In C code if I want to calculate for 221 (@i,j =0,0) ,With border it looks like:

```
 221  221 220
      -----------
 221 |221 220
     |
 71  |71  73
```

In NEON code if I want to calculate for 221 (@i,j =0,0) ,With border it looks like:

```
221 221 221 221     221 220 228 223   230 233 234 235
                    -------------------------------
221 221 221 221    |221 220 228 223   230 233 234 235
                   |
71  71  71  71     |71  73  70  78    92  130 141 143
```

For calculating 221:
In neon code neighbours are showed below and as per requirement it is going wrong:

```
v_m1_m1.0  v_m1_0.0  v_m1_p1.0
v_0_m1.0   v_0_0.0   v_0_p1.0
v_p1_m1.0  v_p1_0.0  v_p1_p1.0

221  221  230
     ---
221 |221| 230
     ---
71   71   92
```

How Can I take care of border with generic code logic ??

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is - the nine v_xxx vectors contain all the data you need for a 3x3 neigbourhood operation - maybe you're getting confused because of the redundant elements in the adjacent vectors ? If so you can just ignore these you'll only be using one element as you shift the pairs of vectors left/right.

Comment: @PaulR,I am expecting rightside neighbour for 221 should be  220 not 230 .with same neon code for 228 ,neighbours are 221(left), 234(right) .And as per C code for 228,neighbours should be 220(left), 223(right) .am I explain enough to clear my question    //    v_m1_m1  v_m1_0  v_m1_p1
    //    v_0_m1   v_0_0   v_0_p1
    //    v_p1_m1  v_p1_0  v_p1_p1

Comment: @PaulR,it will work fine for first iteration :                                                                          v_0_m1: 221 221 221 221  |||                                                                                     v_0_0   : 221 220 228 223  |||                                                                                  v_0_p1 : 220 228 223 230                                                                                       for second iteration i have to increment width(or j) loop by 1 instead of 4 which will destroy the significance of vectorization .

Comment: You need to increment the j loop by 4, since you're processing 4 output elements per iteration - that's the whole point of SIMD.

Comment: Also, important point: for the horizontal neighbourhood operations, you need to use `vextq` to shift a pair of vectors left or right.

Comment: instead of vdupq , I can use vextq

Comment: What I mean is: use `vextq` to "slide" data to the left or right - take two adjacent vectors, e.g. `v_0_m1` and `v_0_0`, and pass these to `vextq` to get a vector which has been shifted by one float element - you can then use this to e.g. incorporate each of the four "left" pixels into your kernel. It probably helps if you sketch this out on paper.

Comment: If your requirement is really with co-efficients of `-1`, `0` and `+1`, then you don't even need to load the zero values and you can just use *add* and *sub* for the other two. Also, it is not clear if your data is always `2xN` or if you are expecting some generic array configuration.  You may certainly optimize to not load the `0` co-efficients.

Comment: @PaulR,I think I am also trying to say same .now with vdupq am getting -> v_0_m1: 221 221 221 221 ||| v_0_0 : 221 220 228 223 ||| v_0_p1 : 220 228 223 230 .So if will use vextq I can get ->  v_0_m1: 221 221 220 228||| v_0_0 : 221 220 228 223 ||| v_0_p1 : 220 228 223 230  ...

Comment: I think you're still thinking only about the border case - I'm talking about the general case, which works for borders and also for interior pixels. I think you're still misunderstanding the crucial point about how the kernel is processed and the vectors are shuffled.

Comment: @PaulR,I request you if possible can you  write pseudo code with NEON so I can understand it

Comment: OK - I've put together a detailed example in an answer below - study this and when you understand how it works then the rest of the pseudo code and the handling of the borders should all make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to understand how to implement a SIMD kernel with neighbourhood operations. This is the important part:

```
//
// you now have a 3x3 arrangement of vectors on which
// you can perform a neighbourhood operation and generate
// 4 output pixels for the current iteration:
//
//    v_m1_m1  v_m1_0  v_m1_p1
//    v_0_m1   v_0_0   v_0_p1
//    v_p1_m1  v_p1_0  v_p1_p1
//
//               |
//               V
//
//              v_out
```

Suppose you want to implement a sum over a cross-shaped kernel, i.e.:

```
y[i][j] = x[i][j] + x[i-1][j] + x[i+1][j] + x[i][j-1] + x[i][j+1];
```

The pseudo code for this in SIMD would be:

```
// sum vertically: x[i][j] + x[i-1][j] + x[i+1][j]
v_out = v_m1_0;
v_out = v_out + v_0_0;      // vaddq
v_out = v_out + v_p1_0;     // vaddq

// add the x[i][j-1] components
v_temp = v_0_m1:v_0_0 >> 1; // vextq - use this to get a right-shifted vector
v_out = v_out + v_temp;     // vaddq

// add the x[i][j+1] components
v_temp = v_0_0:v_0_p1 << 1; // vextq - use this to get a left-shifted vector
v_out = v_out + v_temp;     // vaddq
```

At this point `v_out` now contains the four sums for output elements `y[i][j]`..`y[i][j+3]`. In other words we have evaluated four output points in one kernel. Now we shuffle all our vectors left by one, and load 3 new vectors for the right hand column, and do it all over again with `j += 4`. If you look at the original pseudo-code from the previous question you will see that the border cases are all taken care of by filling a vector with the edge value.